# What is C++ global variables usage risk vs. C?

Tags: c++, c, global-variables

Everywhere I read, people advise against using global variables. If the program consist of single cpp file, will using global variables still be a risk?

Will using global variables in C have the same hard-to-find bugs?

Comment: If the file is very large, yes.

Comment: If you want to make very small apps, you can freely use global variables in some obvious cases. But not in all cases. And in the C language bugs are much more hard-to-find than in C++.

Comment: I think that the risks and problems caused by global variables are not specific to a language. They are to avoid as much as possible in any language.

Comment: @zenith IMO the very large file is a risk itself.